# 'Burn' and custom MBA using WiX - repair failing on NetFx45Web package

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I wrote a custom [Managed Bootstrapper Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx) (MBA) and got most of the functionality to work, except for a repair. Examining the bundle log provides:

```
[335C:3440][2013-04-29T13:51:41]w343: Prompt for source of package:
NetFx45Web, payload: NetFx45Web, path:
D:\dev\Setup\redist\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe
[335C:3440][2013-04-29T13:51:41]e054: Failed to resolve source for file:
D:\dev\Setup\redist\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe, error: 0x80070002.
[335C:3440][2013-04-29T13:51:41]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while
prompting for source (original path
'D:\dev\Setup\redist\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe').
[335C:3440][2013-04-29T13:51:41]e313: Failed to acquire payload: NetFx45Web
to working path:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{ab28ebc1-ce07-49bf-bb1f-bb83a4944aeb}\NetFx45Web,
error: 0x80070002.
[335C:164C][2013-04-29T13:51:41]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while
caching, aborting execution.
[335C:164C][2013-04-29T13:51:41]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070002,
restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[335C:164C][2013-04-29T13:51:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x80070002
[335C:164C][2013-04-29T13:51:43]i410: Variable: ArpSystemComponentCustom = 1
[335C:164C][2013-04-29T13:51:43]i410: Variable: NETFRAMEWORK45 = 378389
```

Interestingly, even though the master log file populates the package specific log file variable name, Burn does not actually generate that file. My guess is it fails before it can do so.

I have included the NetFx45Web package in my WiX bundle as:

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
```

My BootstrapperCore.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper"
                      type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup,
                      BootstrapperCore">
            <section name="host"
                     type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection,
                     BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <host assemblyName="MyCustomMBA">
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Full"/>
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Client"/>
        </host>
    </wix.bootstrapper></configuration>
```

I have looked at related mailing list threads:

- *[Burn - multiple PackageGroupRef in Chain - download issues](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-multiple-PackageGroupRef-in-Chain-download-issues-td7579765.html)*
- *[.NET 4 pre-req in WixNetFxExtension](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/NET-4-pre-req-in-WixNetFxExtension-td7579058.html#a7579070)*

And I have the ResolveSource matter as discussed there, covered.

Why may this be failing on a repair? The install/uninstall works perfectly fine.

Comment: Rob's answer pointed me in the right direction. There was a bug in my code related to the ResolveSource event handler which was causing the repair to fail since Result.Download was not being returned in the callback even though it seemed to be so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `0x80070002` means the file cannot be located. It also does not appear from the log file that the `ResolveSource()` callback returned `Result.Download` to instruct the Burn engine to attempt to reacquire the .NET Framework from the Internet. If the bootstrapper application (BA) returns `Result.Download`, you'll see log entries that talk about acquiring the NETFX4.5 payload from some URL.